# Notation issue (minimum function)

Tags: notation, definition

I have the following notation issue:
Let $d(n,k)$ be a discrete function, I need to define the integer sequence $a(k)$ that, given $k = 2,3,4,\dots$, returns the minimum value of $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $d(n,k)=k$.

My attempt is to write "$(\dots$) $a(k) := \min \{ n(k) : d(n,k)=k\}$, which is $a(k)=3, 6, ?$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$)".

On the other hand, in the same article, I use the notation $\min(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)$ (round brackets instead of curly brackets as above), where $m,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Is my approach clear enough?

Comment: Do not write $a(k) := \min \{ n(k) : d(n,k)=k\}$ but $a(k) := \min \{ n: d(n,k)=k\},$ or even better $a(k) := \min \{ n\in\Bbb Z^+: d(n,k)=k\}.$ Your second notation is unclear.

Comment: Thank you, with $n:=n(k)$ I meant to specify that, in the present case, we need to set the value of $k$ before calculating the value of $n$ (in the rest of the preprint this rule doesn't apply). With the other notation (e.g., $\min(e_n^k(N;x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k),e_n^k(N;x_{1+m_1},x_{2+m_2},\dots,x_{k+m_k}))=e_n^k(N;x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$) I have a list of values describing the eccentricities of some peculiar vertices pertaining to the same graph, where $e_n^k(N;x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)$ is not short to be written as an element of a set.

Comment: Basically, if I am not getting wrong, it would be a good idea to be consistent and use only curly brackets for every $\max\{x_1,x_2\}$ or $\min\{x_1,x_2\}$ that appears in the rest of the preprint. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I thought your second notation was intended to describe the very same integer as the first one, I understand only now that this is not the case. You can keep $\{\}$ for the first one and $()$ for the second one. Each one is the most convenient and usual in each of these two cases. As for $n(k)$, I must insist. The correct notation is $\{ n:d(n,k)=k\},$ not $\{ n(k) : d(n,k)=k\}.$

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!